# Escape the Toxins Airlock (SS13)

Tags: space-station-13

Recently I've been on a kick for Science roles, and most specifically I've had a strong itch to master Toxins...or at least get a basic working knowledge of it in case the station needs some bombs.

The server I play on uses a double airlock to superheat plasma gas before pumping it into a canister.

More than once, I or someone else has walked into that room while the door was open, and someone else pushed the button to "Cycle Out Airlock" (wording may be wrong), at which point the console froze, and the door would not open, no matter what anyone tried to do.

With this very real possibility of dying, how can I escape this chamber, or help someone else escape it once they are inside? Note that we attempted to contact the AI to open the door for us, and were informed that it could not be opened by AI controls.

Comment: YMMV, but depending on the server I think this is a long-standing bug. Short of dismantling the door (or an adjacent wall) I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: Darn.  I had a feeling it might've been a bug.  Our server has gone through some recent updates, but you're probably right.  Guess I know to at least be careful though. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do is cut down the wall next to the door, keep a wrench and a welder on you. You could also try praying but that's a crapshoot.

Comment: Hadn't even thought about busting down the walls.  If it really is glitched out, this'll probably be my best bet.  Thank you.